# Copy a list of files from a file

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I have file containing a list of files separated by end of lines

```
$ cat file_list
file1
file2
file3
```

I want to copy this list of files with FTP

How can I do that ? Do I have to write a script ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn your list of files into list of ftp commands easily enough:

```
(echo open hostname.host; 
 echo user username; 
 cat filelist | awk '{ print "put " $1; }'; 
echo bye) > script.ftp
```

Then you can just run:

`ftp -s script.ftp`

Or possibly (with other versions of ftp)

`ftp -n < script.ftp`

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY ftp implementations vary depending on the platform, try `ftp < script.ftp` or alternately check the man page for your ftp client to run a script, mine appears to have a `-s` but it may be something different for you.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines - the  `somecommand` depends on what you want to do - I don't get that from your question, sorry.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Iterate through lines in file
for line in `cat file.txt`;do
#your ftp command here do something    
 somecommand $line
done
```

edit: If you really want to persue this route for multiple files (you shouldn't!), you can use the following command in place of `somecommand $line`:

```
ncftpput -m -u username -p password ftp.server.com /remote/folder $line
```

ncftpput propably also takes an arbitrary number of files to upload in one go, but I havn't checked it. Notice that this approach will connect and disconnect for every single file!

Comment: Best solution would be a ftp script then. Benj's answer provides an example of that.

Comment: Apparently not doable with my Debian FTP client

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. However, to get you going, I've edited my post to include a command that will upload one file at a time.

Comment: Benj's solution doesn't work because my FTP client doesn't have the -s option. Your solution works for me (Even if it's not good to connect/disconnect for each file)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the very helpful example of how to feed a list of files to ftp. This worked beautifully for me.

After creating my ftp script in Linux (CentOs 5.5), I ran the script with:

```
ftp –n < ../script.ftp
```

My script (with names changed to protect the innocent) starts with:

```
open <ftpsite>
user <userid> <passwd>
cd <remote directory>
bin
prompt
get <file1>
get <file2>
```

And ends with:

```
get <filen-1>
get <filen>
bye
```